# Unknown column in 'where clause' - while using ALL operator in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got the following query:

```
select tem.TEMAT, pra.NR_PRAC 
from tematy tem, pracownicy pra, wyplaty wyp 
where pra.NR_PRAC = wyp.NR_PRAC 
    and wyp.NR_TEM = tem.NR_TEM 
group by tem.TEMAT, pra.NR_PRAC 
having sum(wyp.KWOTA)>=ALL(
    select sum(w.kwota)
    from wyplaty w, pracownicy p
    where w.NR_TEM=tem.NR_TEM and p.NR_PRAC=w.NR_PRAC )
```

which is not working.

Error:

```
SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'uczelnia.tem.NR_TEM' in 'where clause'
```

It seems I can't use `tem.NR_TEM` in the nested query.

Comment: Use `tematy AS tem` for each table reference.

Comment: Can you explain what you want the query to do?  I suspect there is an easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: there are certain tasks called tematy, workers (pracownicy) and payouts (as wyplaty). I want to select one top paid worker for each task.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use it because it is in the group by part ... Try to arrange it in this way :

```
select tem.TEMAT, pra.NR_PRAC,
(select sum(w.kwota) from wyplaty w, pracownicy p where w.NR_TEM=tem.NR_TEM and p.NR_PRAC=w.NR_PRAC) AS irs
 from tematy tem, pracownicy pra, wyplaty wyp where pra.NR_PRAC = wyp.NR_PRAC and wyp.NR_TEM = tem.NR_TEM group by tem.TEMAT, pra.NR_PRAC having sum(wyp.KWOTA)>=ALL(irs)
```

Placing the subquery in the selection list of the outer query should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
select tem.TEMAT, pra.NR_PRAC
from wyplaty wyp join
     tematy tem
     on wyp.NR_TEM = tem.NR_TEM join
     pracownicy pra
     on pra.NR_PRAC = wyp.NR_PRAC
group by tem.TEMAT, pra.NR_PRAC
order by sum(wyp.KWOTA) desc
limit 1;
```

Your problem is because you are accessing a column from the tables after the `group by`, and this column is not in the `select` clause.  The problem is sort of explained in the documentation:

> A similar MySQL extension applies to the HAVING clause. In standard
>   SQL, a query that includes a GROUP BY clause cannot refer to
>   nonaggregated columns in the HAVING clause that are not named in the
>   GROUP BY clause. A MySQL extension permits references to such columns
>   to simplify calculations. This extension assumes that the nongrouped
>   columns will have the same group-wise values. Otherwise, the result is
>   indeterminate.

The "bare" column is the one being used in the correlated subquery.  You could fix the problem by putting the columns in the `select`.  It is better, though, to fix the query.